# Edge (IE11) Canvas offset with SVG drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, html5-canvas, microsoft-edge

I want to draw a serialized DOM element in the canvas. It works perfect on 
Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera but i have problems on Edge (and IE11 (this not crucial)).

This is how I handle the canvas drawing:

```
  this._$svgElement = this._props._svgContainer.find('svg');
  this._initSVGWidth = this._$svgElement.width();
  this._initSVGHeight = this._$svgElement.height();

  var svgURL = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(this._$svgElement[0]);
  var svgString = 'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgURL);

  var newImageWidth, newImageHeight;

  this._ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this._canvas.width, this._canvas.height);

  this._img = new Image();
  this._img.onload = function () {


    if (bowser.msie) {

      newImageHeight = (this._initSVGHeight / this._initSVGWidth) * this._canvas.width;
      newImageWidth = this._canvas.width;

      if (newImageHeight >= this._canvas.height) {
        newImageHeight = this._canvas.height;
        newImageWidth = (this._initSVGWidth / this._initSVGHeight) * this._canvas.height;
      }
    } else {
      newImageHeight = this._img.height / this._img.width * this._canvas.width;
      newImageWidth = this._canvas.width;

      if (newImageHeight > this._canvas.height) {
        newImageHeight = this._canvas.height;
        newImageWidth = this._img.width / this._img.height * this._canvas.height;
      }
    }

    //original image values (never changed)
    this._imgData = {
      x: (this._canvas.width / 2 - newImageWidth / 2),
      y: (this._canvas.height / 2 - newImageHeight / 2),
      w: newImageWidth,
      h: newImageHeight
    };

    this._ctx.drawImage(this._img, this._imgData.x, this._imgData.y, newImageWidth, newImageHeight);

  }.bind(this);
  this._img.src = svgString;
```

The result is a strange offset on the microsoft browsers:
**Edge browser (wrong)**
[image: Microsoft Edge]
**For Example: Chrome Browser (how it should be)**
[image: Chrome Browser]
This is the SVG Test Source: https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg

I don't know what the issue is here. Because even if I try to draw it with `drawImage(this._img, 0, 0)` the resulting image is cut off.

I'm thankful for any suggestions because we are out of any ideas.

Comment: Assuming the first screenshot isn’t an already zoomed-in view, I think this looks like Edge might have problems reading the correct dimensions of your SVG image to begin with. What does that look like, code-wise? What attributes does it have set, in terms of viewbox, width/height, preserveAspectRatio …?

Comment: i just added the svg test source @CBroe forgot it

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Where do `_initSVGWidth` and `_initSVGHeight` etc get set?  Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulLeBeau added this. it just gets the size of the SVG. This part works thats why i didn't provide it.

Comment: No, that part doesn't work and is most probably the issue. IE is known to be really bad at getting/setting svg dimensions. Now we know you are getting it from the CSS computed values, we'll even need to get the CSS that is applied on this `<svg>` node and its parents. But since your svg has absolute width and height attributes, you could simply use that instead of the computed ones, because it is the ones taht should be set on the `<img>` (even though IE won't set it itself...)